# Raw SQL with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm very new in the world of Elixir and Phoenix Framework. I'm trying to follow TheFireHoseProject tutorial, but having problems with querying raw SQL with Ecto. The tutorial says this should work:

```
defmodule Queries do
def random do
  query = Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.query(
    Repo,
    "SELECT id, saying, author from quotes ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
    [])
  %Postgrex.Result{rows: [row]} = query
  {id, saying, author} = row
  %Splurty.Quote{id: id, saying: saying, author: author}
end
end
```

I'm getting a runtime error that the Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.query doesn't exist (undefined function).

I tried to search the Ecto documentation and found that there might be a function called run_query, but it doesn't work either.

I think I'm using Ecto 1.1.4 and I didn't find any good (up-to-date) samples of how can I query raw SQL with Ecto.

The link to the firehoseproject is: http://phoenix.thefirehoseproject.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
alias Ecto.Adapters.SQL

querystring = "..."

result = SQL.query(Repo, querystring , [])
```

And then you can add the result to a list for example like this:

```
list = []

case result do
  {:ok, columns} ->
            list = for item <- columns.rows do
                List.first(item)
            end
  _ -> IO.puts("error")
end
```

Comment: The query seems to work now, but I have problems mapping the results to my object model (Quote). I think it's just me learning elixir in general.

Answer (score 11):

If all you need is just to add a raw SQL to otherwise normal Ecto query you can use [fragment/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1):

```
from q in Quote, order_by: fragment("RANDOM()"), limit: 1
```

It's often enough and it's much easier to handle. You can generally use fragment/1 in any part of Ecto query. For even nicer use, you can define a macro that will allow you to fit nicely into Ecto's DLS:

```
defmodule QueryHelpers do
  defmacro random() do
    quote do
      fragment("RANDOM()")
    end
  end
end
```

And later use it:

```
import QueryHelpers
from q in Quote, order_by: random(), limit: 1
```

Comment: Basically this would solve my current problem, but for the sake of learning I want to see how I can execute complete raw sql with ecto. Anyway, this is also really nice to know and will probably come handy in the future, thanks!