# How to get DB values returned by raw sql with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have made a complicated SQL. so that I use raw query.
I've already referred `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042888/raw-sql-with-ecto`
But I still stacked.

```
query = "select item_id, sum(unit) amount from sales where item_id = ? "
result = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(Repo, query, [item_id])
```

However I have no idea how to retrieve DB values like Ecto results in general.
I hope I get values like Map with key & value whatever.

The result is blow.

```
%Mariaex.Result{columns: ["item_id", "amount"], connection_id: nil, last_insert_id: nil, num_rows: 1, rows: [[42, #Decimal<4>]]}, :get, [])
```

Should I retrieve by myself or there are general and smart way?
Hopefully, the last result is output for Phoenix templates html.

I'm trying to change result value to Map like this.

```
item_result =
  {:ok, result} ->
    rows = result.get(:rows)
    columns = result.get(:columns)
    Enum.zip(columns, rows)
```

But it is hard for elixir novice.

Comment: I find no better way in the documentation, so I would use pattern matching to assign the values of the rows to the variables you want. You could even write a helper function that does exactly what I think you want. (Transfer these results into maps).

Comment: Only I want to know now is how to get columns name and rows values. then put them together and change map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to treat raw SQL with Ecto. 
I just divided problems into small parts.

(1) `sum()` returns Decimal value in case of mysql.

```
query = "select item_id, sum(unit) amount from sales where item_id = ? "
result = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(Repo, query, [item_id])
```

=> I need convert `#Decimal` value to `#Integer` using Decimal.to_integer/1 in Elixir.

(2) `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query` returns {:ok, results}

=> I should have received by `{:ok, results}` as return value.

(3) Retrieving `:columns` and `:rows`

```
columns = results.columns
rows = results.rows
```

(4) Put these values colums and rows together

```
Enum.zip(columns, rows) |> Enum.into(%{})
```